# can't catch adal:loginSuccess when not using popup

Tags: adal, adal.js

I have an angularjs SPA with ui.router.
in my module config I have:

```
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
      .state('welcome', {
          url: '/',
          template: '<div><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary\" ui-sref=\"login\"><i class=\"fa fa-sign-in\"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Login</button></div>',
      })
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            template: '<h4> logging in ... </h4>',
            controller: 'LoginController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            requireADLogin: true
        })
        .state('loggedin', {
            url: '/loggedin',
            templateUrl: '/app/logged-in.html',
            requireADLogin: true
        })
        .state('logout', {
            url: '/logout',
            template: '<h4> logging out ... </h4>',
            controller: 'LogoutController'
        }) ;
   adalProvider.init(
   {
       instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
       tenant: 'mytenant.onmicrosoft.com',
       clientId: 'myappid',           
       extraQueryParameter: 'nux=1',
       popUp: true,
       cacheLocation: 'localStorage' // enable this for IE, as sessionStorage does not work for localhost.
   },
   $httpProvider
   );
```

in LoginController:

```
function loginController($rootScope, $state, adalService) {
    /* jshint validthis:true */
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'login';
    vm.activate = activate;
    activate();
    function activate() {
        adalService.login();
    }
    $rootScope.$on('adal:loginSuccess', function (event, token) {
        console.log('loggedin');
        $state.go('loggedin');
    });
}
```

if I remove the popUp setting, I can't catch the adal:loginSuccess and so I always get back to default state (welcome screen).

Also, I know I can set the redirectUri, but I'm not sure how to do it. I've tried with http://myappurl/loggedin, trying to trigger the loggedin state, but it doesn't work.

Thanks

PS: template for welcome state is inline because for an unknown reason, if I use templateUrl, it throws an error (before introducing adal, it was working fine)

Comment: Have you fixed this issue now?

Comment: Hi @FeiXue-MSFT, I've settled to the popup, but I still can't figure out the templateUrl thing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to reproduce the issue, however failed. Here is the script which works well for your reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <base href="/">
    <title></title>
    <script src="node_modules\angular\angular.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules\adal-angular\lib\adal-angular.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules\adal-angular\lib\adal.js"></script>

     <script src="node_modules\angular-ui-router\release\angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules\angular-route\angular-route.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="LoginController">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li ng-show="userInfo.isAuthenticated"><a class="btn btn-link"  ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
                <li ng-hide="userInfo.isAuthenticated" ><a class="btn btn-link" ng-click="login()">Login</a></li>
                <a ui-sref="home">Home</a> | <a ui-sref="about">About</a>
                <div ui-view></div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['AdalAngular', 'ui.router', 'ngRoute'])
.config(['$httpProvider', 'adalAuthenticationServiceProvider', '$stateProvider', '$routeProvider','$locationProvider','$urlRouterProvider', function ($httpProvider, adalProvider, $stateProvider, $routeProvider,$locationProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {

 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true,false).hashPrefix('!');

 $stateProvider.state("home",{
       template: "<h1>HELLO!</h1>"
 }).state("about",{
          templateUrl: '/app/about.html',
         requireADLogin: true
 })

    adalProvider.init(
       {
           instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
           tenant: '',
           clientId: '',           
           extraQueryParameter: 'nux=1',
           popUp:true
       },
       $httpProvider
       );
}])
    myApp.controller('LoginController', ['$rootScope','$scope', '$http', 'adalAuthenticationService', '$location','$stateParams','$state',  
                            function ($rootScope,$scope, $http, adalService, $location,  $stateParams,$state) {

                                    $scope.login = function () {
                                        adalService.login();
                                    };
                                    $scope.logout = function () {
                                        adalService.logOut();
                                    };

                                    $rootScope.$on('adal:loginSuccess', function (event, token) {
                                    console.log('loggedin');
                                    $state.go('about');
                                });
    }]);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I used the latest version of `adal-angular` library(v1.0.14). This code sample will go to the **about** state after login with the popup page. Please let me know if the code works. And if you still have the problem, would you mind sharing with us a demo which could run?

Comment: Hi Fei!
Thanks for your answer. I think you missed a part of my comment:
" if I remove the popUp setting, I can't catch the adal:loginSuccess and so I always get back to default state (welcome screen)."

I want to remove the popup.

Also, could you address the other two issues, please?

Comment: This issue is caused that the state is initialized when the location is changed. The `adal:loginSuccess` is fired when the page is redirect back from Azure AD with the hash value(id_token etc.)  After that the `adal` library will remove this hash value which cause the state is initialized again. For the SAP application, the popup is recommend. instead of page redirection. I suggest that you use the popup as a workaround.

Comment: And if you real want to work with the full page redirection in the scenario, I suggest that you reopen a new issue from [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues).

Comment: Ok @feixue, I get it. It would be nice not to have a popup, but I can live with that. Can you tell me anything about this cumbersome thing: "template for welcome state is inline because for an unknown reason, if I use templateUrl, it throws an error (before introducing adal, it was working fine)" ? Thanks

Comment: The code works well for me when I using the templateUrl as the code in the post. Please feel free to let me know whether the code works for you. Based on the code, you doesn't redirect to the welcome state, if you still have the problem, you may share a runnable code sample to help troubleshooting.

Comment: Hi @FeiXue-MSFT, please check it here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlBevQQ5u1azkIQfIXqPaaPNG8ziQQ
Thanks

Comment: Based on the code, you were using the `~1.0.0-rc.1` version of `angular-ui-router`. After I switched to the latest release version(`0.4.2`), the issues was fixed. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: You're right! I'll report this the ui.router team.
Thanks!